# flask-socketio --> Client not receiving emits from server

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I 've searched here for similar problems but couldn't find an exact answer. I'm definately no socketio specialist, so please forgive me in advance...

To put it simple and in short: when I perform send() from my server (py script) preceded by a '@socket.on('message')' all is received fine on the client side. However when I use emit() on a manually triggered def, nothing is shown on client side.

Here is my simplified code:

server - app.py

```
app=Flask(__name__) app.config["SECRET_KEY"]="secretkey"

socket = SocketIO(app, logger=True)

somelist = ["el1", "el2", "el3", "el4"] 
i=0

@app.route("/") def main():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route("/test2")
def test2():
    print("called test2")
    manual_callback("note 1")

@socket.on('message') 
def handlemsg(msg):
    global i
    if i < len(somelist):
        socket.send(somelist[i] + " - " + msg)
        i+=1

def manual_callback(note):
    print("manual_callback triggered")
    socket.emit('updateData', {"data": "this the data to show - " + note}, namespace="/test2")
    print("trigger done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket.run(app)
```

Client - main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        socket = io();
        socket.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        
        socket.on('updateData',function(data){
            console.log('called updateData');
            console.log(data);
            console.log('ended call');
        })

        socket.on('connect',function(){
            console.log('CONNECT');
            socket.send('a');
        })

        socket.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            socket.send('b');
        })    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

*What works fine:*
After connecting, 'socket.on('connect',...) is triggered in main.html and 'CONNECT' is printed in the browser log followed by the 4 elements in somelist.

*What doesn't work like I would expect:*
After navigating to localhost/test2, def manual_callback() is called. So I would expect that on client side, 'socket.on('updateData'...)' gets triggered and messages 'called UpdateData', 'this the data to show - note 1' and 'ended call' appear in the browser's log. **But the latter does not seem to happen**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you navigating to the `/test2` page in the browser? The Socket.IO connection goes away when you navigate to a new page, WebSocket connections are tied to the page, they cannot be maintained across pages.

Comment: An answer from the master himself, thank you for the quick response!
I didn't know that... I removed the "namespace="/test2" and returned "main.html" instead of the h1 tag and now it works like I desired. Thank you!